# Windows permission - creating a new process with a name

Tags: windows, command-line, permissions, cmd.exe, windows-server

I have a probably permission problem on Windows. On machines not controlled by domain controller I can run this without problem:

```
cmd /C start "KILLERCMD" cmd /C CMD
```

then when listing list of processes with:

```
cmd /C TASKLIST /V /FO CSV /NH
```

I can find "KILLERCMD" in there. However, on machines controlled by domain controller, the process is there, but the name is just "N/A"

See the difference:

```
    not working machine: 
"cmd.exe","2580","Services","0","1,972 K","Unknown","DOMAIN\user","0:00:00","N/A"
    working machine: 
"cmd.exe","4428","Services","0","2,032 K","Running","FQDN","0:00:00","Administrator: KILLERCMD"
```

the DOMAIN\user is in the Administrator group BTW.

Anyone any tip why this is happening? I am kinda lost here.

Thanks!